# UIPickerView content flowing unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I am using `UIDatePicker` and `UIPickerView` in my app. But both the controls are showing weird behaviour. When I scroll the content in the picker, it flows outside the picker and does not scroll as it is supposed to. My implementation is as below.

```
sexArray = @[@"Male", @"Female"];
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 150)];
[picker setDataSource: self];
[picker setDelegate: self];
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
genderTF.inputView = picker;


#pragma mark -- UIPICKERVIEW METHODS

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return sexArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 1;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
UILabel *retval = (UILabel*)view;
if (!retval) {
    retval = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
}

retval.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:15.0f];
retval.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6;
[retval setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
retval.text = [sexArray objectAtIndex:row];

return retval;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
[genderTF setText:sexArray[component]];
}
```

When the same code is used in another app (for testing), it works as expected.

[image: Editing began]

[image: When content Scrolled]

Comment: retval = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
 to 
    retval = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];

Comment: @rkmakwana i think the `font size` or the `minimumScaleFactor` may affects this. I think the font size is higher than the label height. try to set background color for the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the implementation was correct on my part. The problem was because of a third party library.

I was using a pod `SLPagingView` in my project which made the `UIPickerView' act weird. I couldn't find a solution and ended up in replacing the pod with similar pod.

Details [link](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingView/issues/37)

Comment: thanks for the solution i was also faced same from last couple of day now finally get to know the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `titleForRow` instead of `viewForRow`.

```
 -(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{


return [sexArray objectAtIndex:row];

 }
```

**Update :**

If you are using picker view as `input view` of `textfield` then don't init it with frame.

Init picker view like,

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same behaviour. And as I mentioned in the question, it happens with UIDatePicker too.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem cause I used a third-party lib called "SLPagingView", I don't know whether you used it, too.
If you did, this may help. I've just solved this problem by modifying the -(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame and -(void)updateConstraints methods in the "UIScrollView+UpdateContentSize.m" file, and here is my code:

```
#pragma mark - OVERRIDE
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    // Scale the content size
    Class UIPickerTableView = NSClassFromString(@"UIPickerTableView");
    if ([self class] == UIPickerTableView) {
        return;
    }else {
        [self updateContentSize];
    }
}

-(void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];
    // Scale the content size
    Class UIPickerTableView = NSClassFromString(@"UIPickerTableView");
    if ([self class] == UIPickerTableView) {
        return;
    }else {
        [self updateContentSize];
    }
}
```

This works and wish it could help you too.